# Python pool.map() list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a sample code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Pool

url = ['https://www.google.com','https://www.facebook.com']
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def browser(x):
    driver.get(url[x])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(2)
    pool.map(browser,url)
```

It gets the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    pool.map(browser,url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `x` is a string (url). It might be more helpful if you renamed `url` into `urls` and `x` to `url`. `urls[url]` is nonsense. You probably meant `driver.get(url)`.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use globals

Comment: I figured that out. Thanks for your help